# filtering XML attribute and only listing the greater [x] amount of the parent node

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

```
<book>
 <name>Book 1</name>
 <author age="02">Author 1</author>
</book>
<book>
 <name>Book 2</name>
 <author age="01">Author 2</author>
</book>
<book>
 <name>Book 3</name>
 <author age="04">Author 3</author>
</book>
<book>
 <name>Book 4</name>
 <author age="03">Author 4</author>
</book>
```

I need list the book name starting with the greatest of authors age but only the greater two... I would need to return the nameIn this example, the filter would list Book 3 and then Book 4, in that order.

This is hurting my brain and don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You could create [Value Objects](http://www.flashmonkey.co.uk/using-value-objects-in-flash/) from your XML data and store them in an Array.

After that you can simply sort your Array using [Array sortOn()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn()) then return the first two results.